# How to set the path for reference DLLs in console application (Visual Studio)?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, timer-jobs

I have created a solution which has multiple project (i.e. Business Layer, Database Layer etc..). This solution also has one console application and I've added the reference of another projects dll (business layer and database layer). Now, I am following below steps to deploy it on server:

1. Build the console application.
2. Copy the code and replace it on server (I
   already have created one windows server and I've schedule it to run
   at some interval)

Now the problem is, console application is searching the dll as per my local path and it is not referencing to the same folder where I've deployed the code.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How have you added the dlls?

Comment: Clicked on references -> add new references and from Projects I have selected the required dlls. I also have setup the copy local = true

Comment: Is this a web project - if so whats in the web.config for this dll?

Comment: @jProg2015 No this is not a web Project. It's a console application.